# Storing an integer variable in local storage in alpine.js

Tags: javascript, html, dom, local-storage, alpine.js

I wanted to store an integer value in local storage using alpine.js

There is a button that increments the value by 1 when pressed.

Here is how I thought it should be:

```
<div id="greeting" class="inner" x-data="{ $store.integer: 0 }">
    <button class="button bouncy" @click="$store.integer+=1" x-text="$store.integer + ' is the number'"></button>
</div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => 
    Alpine.store('store', integer)
    })
</script>
```

This didn't work. I tried some other implementations, but none of them seemed to work. I also tried not adding the $store, since it showed the integer as "undefined" when I did that.

Answer (score 1):

Alpine has the persist plugin which looks like it might suit your needs.

https://alpinejs.dev/plugins/persist

```
<div x-data="{ count: $persist(0) }">
<button x-on:click="count++">Increment</button>

<span x-text="count"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: It says count is not defined

Comment: nevermind, I forgot to add the plugin

Comment: Hope it worked out for you!

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of mistakes in the example code. The corrected version is the following:

```
<div id="greeting" class="inner" x-data="{}">
    <button class="button bouncy" @click="$store.integer += 1" x-text="$store.integer + ' is the number'"></button>
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    Alpine.store('integer', 0)
})
</script>
```

1. When you create a new variable in the store, the first argument is the name of the variable, the second is its initial value.
2. In the component, you don't have to recreate the variable in the `x-data` attribute, since it is defined in the `alpine:init` hook. So you can use just an empty `x-data` (assuming you don't have other variables in the component).
3. You have a missing `{` after `=>`.